# In c# should I ever use ToArray() before an Any() to avoid multiple enumeration

Tags: .net

Given an example something like this:

```
x = SomeFunctionReturningIEnumerable().ToArray();


if (!x.Any())
{
    //... (some code here that doesn't enumerate x)
    //...
    foreach (var item in x)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

In what circumstances is the `ToArray()` call a good idea, and in what circumstances is it a bad idea? And in which circumstances does it not really matter at all.

Comment: Does the enumerator do something expensive and/or non-repeatable?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for generalisation: would you say: if it does something expensive or non-repeatable then I should call `ToArray()` otherwise don't.

Comment: Calling `ToArray` might be expensive if collection is big and does not implement `ICollection<T>`. I would advice you **not** to call `ToArray()` unless you're not sure that method returns the same results between both `Any` call and `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If enumeration is especially expensive and you don't want to buffer the entire sequence, I would use [Ix-Main](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Main/)'s `Memoize()`. This will buffer for two iterations:

```
x = SomeFunctionReturningIEnumerable().Memoize(2);

if (!x.Any())
{
    //... (some code here that doesn't enumerate x)
    //...
    foreach (var item in x)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Any() destroys its Enumerator immediately, so only the first value will get buffered -- once the `foreach` passes it, it'll be streaming from source again.